# python get data from div blocks

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to parse  div block using Beautiful Soup

Which is

```
<div class="same-height-left" style="height: 20px;"><span class="value-frame">&nbsp;whatever</span></div>
```

I want to get [what i expect]:

`whatever` or `<span class="value-frame">&nbsp;whatever</span>`

I tried

```
response = requests.get('http://example.com')
response.raise_for_status()
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text)

div = soup.find('div', class_="same-height-left")
```

Result

> None

And

```
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text)

div = soup.find_all('div', class_="same-height-left")
```

Result

> []

Comment: Try `bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")`

Comment: @SimonKirsten the result is the source code ,,  then ?

Comment: ANd when you try span = soup.find('span', class_="value-frame") does it find anything?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """<div class="same-height-left" style="height: 20px;"><span class="value-frame">&nbsp;whatever</span></div>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

method1 = soup.find('div').text
method2 = soup.find('div').find('span').text
method3 = soup.find('span', class_='value-frame').text

print 'Result of method 1:' + method1  # prints " whatever"
print 'Result of method 2:' + method2  # prints " whatever"
print 'Result of method 3:' + method3  # prints " whatever"
```

Comment: `method3 = soup.find('span', class_='value-frame').text` Thanks :)

Comment: can you tell me if something like this http://pastebin.com/BG8yzifd how can i get the text `firstword` and `secondword`

Comment: `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`

`soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')`

`elements = soup.select('tr > td > div > span')`
`print [x.text for x in elements]`